# numpy delete not deleting element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Under what circumstances would bumpy.delete simply return a copy of the original array, unaltered?

If I do a simple example as follows, then things work as advertised:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(0, 10)
>>> numpy.delete(a, [1])
>>> array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

but when I work with an array created from a list by numpy.array() then things don't work anymore.

```
    scale = [Params.BADVALUE, Params.BADVALUE+1]
    for h in xrange(500, 3001, 500):
        scale.append(h)
    scale += [4000, 5000]
    for h in xrange(7000, 17001, 2000):
        scale.append(h)
    scale.append(upper_bound)
    self.SCALE = numpy.array(scale)
    self.SCALE_WRITE = numpy.delete(self.SCALE, [1000.0])
```

self.SCALE_WRITE ends up being identical to self.SCALE

I've checked that self.SCALE is indeed 1-dimensional and that no extra dimensions have been added by mistake.

It's easy enough to code my way around this but I would still like to know what I'm doing wrong.

Catherine

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) for `numpy.delete`? You're using it wrong; it doesn't take the arguments you think it does.

Comment: @Kasramvd: [No, that's not it.](http://ideone.com/rfkvbt)

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a float instead of an integer in the last line ?

Comment: Always check the docs of a module before using it.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it appears that you are simply trying to delete an index that is out of the array; hence the lack of change ...
From your code `len(scale)` gives only 17 .

For the record as the [doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) indicates, `numpy.delete(arr,obj)` will try to delete the element **returned by arr[obj]** for a 1-D array so :

- numpy.delete(arr,0)
- numpy.delete(arr,[0])
- numpy.delete(arr,0.0)
- numpy.delete(arr,[0.0])

will all **delete `arr[0]` which is the zero-th element** of that 1-D array.

Answer (score 0):

first, `delete` does not operate in place:

```
In [849]: a=np.arange(10)
In [850]: np.delete(a,[1])
Out[850]: array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])  # returned array
In [851]: a
Out[851]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])  # not change in a
```

If I do an out of bounds delete with a scalar, I get an error:

```
In [853]: a1=np.delete(a,11)
...
IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10
```

But if the delete is a list, it appears the bounds check does not operate (is there a parameter for that?)

```
In [854]: a1=np.delete(a,[11])
In [855]: a1
Out[855]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

`a1` is a copy though; changing one of its values does not affect `a`.

```
In [858]: a1[-1]=100
In [859]: a1
Out[859]: array([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8, 100])
In [860]: a
Out[860]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

`np.delete` is a complicated Python function, written to be quite general.  It can be studied.  It is not a fundamental function.  It is not doing anything you can't do just as well with basic array operations like masking, indexing and/or selective copying. And it isn't going to be faster.

================

You can study `np.delete`.  My memory is that it often does the following:

`delete` via mask for scalar:

```
In [863]: mask=np.ones(a.shape,dtype=bool)
In [864]: mask[1]=False
In [865]: a[mask]
Out[865]: array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

for list:

```
In [866]: mask=np.ones(a.shape,dtype=bool)
In [867]: mask[[1,3,5]]=False
In [868]: a[mask]
Out[868]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

==================

Recreation of your script with added displays:

```
In [874]: scale=[1,2]
In [875]: for h in range(500,3001,500):scale.append(h)
In [876]: len(scale)
Out[876]: 8
In [877]: scale+=[4000,5000]
In [878]: for h in range(7000,17001,2000):scale.append(h)
In [879]: len(scale)
Out[879]: 16
In [880]: scale.append(1000)
In [881]: Scale=np.array(scale)
In [882]: Scale.shape
Out[882]: (17,)
In [883]: np.delete(Scale,[1000])
Out[883]: 
array([    1,     2,   500,  1000,  1500,  2000,  2500,  3000,  4000,
        5000,  7000,  9000, 11000, 13000, 15000, 17000,  1000])
```

So there are only 17 items in the array, not a 1000.  And as I illustrated with a delete list, it does not raise an error if it is out of bounds.  Hence the `delete` result is a copy of the input.

By the way I create that same array with an array concatenate

```
In [886]: np.r_[1, 2, 500:3001:500, [4000,5000], 7000:17001:2000, 1000]
Out[886]: 
array([    1,     2,   500,  1000,  1500,  2000,  2500,  3000,  4000,
        5000,  7000,  9000, 11000, 13000, 15000, 17000,  1000])
```

Even sticking with the list I can avoid the loops with `extend`:

```
In [887]: scale=[1,2]
In [888]: scale.extend(range(500,3001,500))
In [889]: scale.extend([4000,5000])
In [890]: scale.extend(range(7000,17001,2000))
In [891]: scale.append(1000)
```

Comment: I see my mistake.  I misread the documentation and see that numpy.delete works by index number, and not value.  Therefore an easy hack is:                                                                                                              a = numpy.arange(100, 110)                                                                                          b = numpy.delete(a, numpy.where(a == 101)) but that could be horribly inefficient for large arrays.  Mine is very small for this particular problem ..

Comment: Finding the value to delete shouldn't be that expensive; but since `delete` is not in-place any deletion requires copying most of the values from the original to the new.  But timings can determine where the costs are.

Comment: In fairness to you, @user3014653, [numpy's documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) doesn't appear to explicitly indicate whether the "obj" argument, which should "indicate which sub-arrays to remove" should specify as indices or as values.

Comment: @Eee, `For a one dimensional array, this returns those entries not returned by arr[obj].` seems sufficiently explicit to me.  `obj` is used as an index.

Comment: Fair enough, @hpaulj!